# spring security is remember me user authenticated by username

Tags: java, spring, authentication, grails, spring-security

In short:

I want to know if a user - given by the username - is authenticated or not.
I want to know this for Username / password auths given by `org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`

but also for remember me users given by `org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken`

The username / password part is easy:

```
class someService {
    def userDetailsService
    def sessionRegistry

    boolean hasUserUserNameAndPasswordAuth(String username){
        def principal = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(theUser.email, false)
        userSession = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal, false).find { !it.isExpired() } 

        if (userSession)
            return true
        else
            return false
    }
}
```

All users which are authenticated by username and password will return true on the function above. But all remembermy users will return false.

Even this method call `sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()` will return a list which does not contains principals that are authenticated by remember me token.

Why does the sessionRegistry not return users with a remember me authentication? Don't they also have a session?!

To get remember me authentifications, I played around with the `rememberMeServices` class. This class has a method called `autoLogin(request, response)` that returns the authentication of the current request. But this doesn't help me because I want to know if a user given by a username has a valid authentification, not the current one)

I think I have 3 options:
a) Find you why sessionRegistry does not return sessions for remember me authentifications

b) find a service that returns all principals that have a valid (from the expire date point of view) token

c) write a filter that intercepts every request and creates a new session - that can be found by the `sessionRegistry` - when a user has a remember me auth based on calling `rememberMeServices.autoLogin(request, response)`.

What do you think?

Comment: Check this out: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html

Comment: In an old code i used to get user name with "sec.username()"

Comment: The problem here is not to get the user based on username but to check if a user has a valid remember me token